# Get token for any AAD user

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

A requirement is set upon me to implement impersonation for developers, of course only for development environment. I was wondering if it is possible to request a token for any AAD user without knowing the password. The flow I would want is:

1. Developer goes to web application to select a user he wants to impersonate.
2. The web application checks if the developer is in the AAD.
3. The web application checks if the developer has the necessary rights to impersonate.
4. The web application returns a token valid for the user the developer selected.
5. The developer can use this token to authenticate against the API, and for all intents and purposes is the impersonated user.

Any good alternatives to this approach are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot impersonate a user like this.
You can acquire an access token if you know their password and they don't have MFA etc. with the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant flow.

But if you want to do it in a better way, you could have the users who you wish to impersonate login to your app.
Acquire an access token + refresh token for them.
Then store the refresh token securely.
Now you can use the refresh token at any time along with your app's client credentials to acquire a token for that user.
Refresh tokens can and do expire though, for example if the user's password is changed.
But this could allow you to implement what you want.

Comment: You had me until the refresh token expires on password change. There is a company rule where passwords have to change every month. Since the users to impersonate are never developers, they never login to the test system. I cannot demand they log in every month just for our whims. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: No, I don't think so :( By the way, did you know that such change rules are not recommended since they result in poor passwords? I understand you might not be able to decide that though.